# What does "Everyone's" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

In *Molly's Game* 2017, Molly speaks about Harlan and Brad playing in poker game
in which Brad won:

> Molly: It wasn't even that it was that much money. Harlan only lost
> about $40,000 on the hand. But a circuit breaker blew, and Harlan was
> out for blood  now. **Everyone's**.

What does "Everyone's" mean?
Does Molly is suggesting that Harlan was looking to take revenge on everyone,
not just Brad who won the hand?

Comment: Yes you are correct. It means "everyone's blood".  It's an example of ellipsis. The omitted word is obvious from the context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Everyone's *blood*.

The idiom "[be out for blood](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/out-for-blood)" means "be intending to attack (someone), or make them suffer in some way". It means that the person is not willing to compromise or play "nicely".